# MVC custom routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am using MVC 5, and trying to create custom routing in Route.Config i.e. Home but when i run application, it takes me straight to my custom routing which i don't want. the default is login, success of which should lead to Dashboard/Home (controller/Action) but I want to use only Home (Action Name only). Many Thanks

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //---In order to use only Action Title in URL--//
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "{action}/{id}",
             new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        //-----default routing---//
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        "Home",
        "Home/{id}",
         new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate within action to a new action of a different controller then you have to mention like below.

If you want to navigate to Home from your login then you really dont have to change the route. In your login action on success call

```
RedirectToAction(String, String)    Redirects to the specified action using the action name and controller name.
```

Provide

```
RedirectToAction("Home", "Dashboard");
```